# Is there a way to find a list of over a thousand files any faster using File::Find::Rule?

Tags: perl

My main directory has a lot of sub folders, each containing over a thousand files. I need to fetch the names of all files with an extension of `.xml`, `aux`, or `.tex` and store them in an array.

```
use File::Find::Rule;

$path_dir = "d:/testing/Projects/";

my @allfiles = File::Find::Rule->file()->
        name( "*.xml", "*.aux", "*.tex" )->
        in( $path_dir );

print join "\n", @allfiles;

system 'pause';
```

The above code is working fine but it takes over a minute to run. Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: What do you mean by "timings"? Do you just want to do this faster?

Comment: @Borodin: Exactly. Its taken more than a minute.

Comment: Are all of these files in a subfolder of your main directory? It can often be faster to use `glob`, or even to shell out to a `dir` command. Try `my @allfiles = grep /\.(?:xml|aux|tex)$/i, \`dir /s /b 'D:\testing\Projects'\` ` (untested)

Comment: @Borodin: `glob` doesn't fetching files recursively into `sub` `subdirectories`. I have tried this. No luck.

Comment: What do you mean "no luck"?

Comment: See also [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

Comment: @Borodin: Instead finding the root cause.

Comment: Removing `->file()` might avoid the `stat` check which might speeds things up. After all, you're not going to have a dir named `foo.xml`

Comment: I'd expect that running in multiple processes/threads (over major first-level subfolders for example) should be fruitfull, since some concurrency should be happening (even for disk reads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
name( "*.xml", "*.aux", "*.tex" )->
```

with this:

```
name( qr/\.(xml|aux|tex)$/ )->
```